# How to get original pdf from embed type=application/pdf using java

Tags: html, pdf, download, embed, jsoup

I'm using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse some HTML to get some PDF url.

The PDF is shown in an `<embed>` tag like:

```
<html>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38)">
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://www.domain.com/apdf_id.pdf?tp=&amp;arnumber=1253069&amp;isnumber=28038" type="application/pdf">
</body>
</html>
```

How can I get the PDF URL from that page, so that I can download it to local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the `<embed type="application/pdf">` element and get its `src` attribute as absolute URL.

```
String pdfURL = document.select("embed[type=application/pdf").first().absUrl("src");
```

You could also select specifically the `<embed name="plugin">` instead.

```
String pdfURL = document.select("embed[name=plugin").first().absUrl("src");
```

Then you can use `java.net.URL` to obtain it in flavor of `InputStream`.

```
InputStream input = new URL(pdfURL).openStream();
```

Finally just write it to an arbitrary `OutputStream` such as `FileOutputStream` the usual way.

#### See also:

- [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests/2793153#2793153)